# Leaflet: Popup of polygon and function onMapClick(e)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

To my leaflet map i've added a function onMapClick(e) to show the current coordinates. At the same time, i've created a polygon with a popup.

If i click on the polygon, the current coordinates occur instead of the polygon's popup window. It seems like the function overwrites the polygon popup window.

Do you have an idea, how i can solve this problem?

Thank you so much!

See my code fragments below:

```js
// popup with coordinates

   var popup = L.popup();

   function onMapClick(e) {
      popup
          .setLatLng(e.latlng)
          .setContent("Koordinaten (WGS-84): " + e.latlng.lng.toFixed(8) + " E, " + e.latlng.lat.toFixed(8) + " N")
          .openOn(map)
   }

   map.on('click', onMapClick);





// polygon   

            var POI_Alte_Baeckerei = L.polygon([
    [46.97482843, 7.43818506],
    [46.97484775, 7.43860268],
    [46.97469802, 7.43860976],
    [46.97464490, 7.43903446],
    [46.97456279, 7.43902031],
    [46.97455313, 7.43825584]
    ]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Alte B&auml;ckerei');

   var activated_on_map_detail = L.layerGroup([map_detail, POI_Alte_Baeckerei]);

   map.on('zoomend', function () {
     if (map.getZoom() >= 17.6 && map.hasLayer(activated_on_map_detail)==false) {
       map.addLayer(activated_on_map_detail);
     }
     if (map.getZoom() < 17.6 && map.hasLayer(activated_on_map_detail)) {
       map.removeLayer(activated_on_map_detail);
     }
   });
```

Comment: Your code works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/hlMSmVJJ6KERMbKR0HB8?p=preview

Comment: Also like @FranceImage i'm unable to reproduce your problem, could you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: thanks. i think the problem was that i used the beta version of leaflet. with v0.7.7 it runs.